# Can some body help me in online server (2 free server)

Tags: mysql, data-structures, server

I want to add foreign key in table from primary key table....but the problem my table should be innoDB storage...I dont find the innoDB in operation what can I do to add it and and active it in the table...

Comment: You want to add a foreign key. Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your table engine is innodb by below command-

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM your_db LIKE 'your_table';
```

Check 2nd column ENGINE, it will show your table engine if it is not innodb then first change it, you can use below command-

```
alter table your_table engine=innodb;
```

Then you can create foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB is a storage engines for MySQL.To maintain data integrity, InnoDB supports FOREIGN KEY referential-integrity constraints.

Add foreign key in your table like this.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename2
  ADD CONSTRAINT `id_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Id`) REFERENCES tablename1 (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```